# Fonts table remains empty after retrieving windows fonts with extrafont package

Tags: r, pdf, fonts

For saving ggplots with font name Calibri to pdf files, I tried to use the `extrafont` package in order to be able to use this font type within ggplot2.

These were the steps I took:

```
font_import()
```

After getting all the fonts (during that proces nothing seems wrong), I get this error:

```
Scanning afm files in <<library path>>/extrafontdb/metrics
Error in if (grepl("Bold", weight)) { : argument is of length zero
```

together with errors like these:

```
Warning messages:
1: In readLines(srcfile) :
  invalid input found on input connection 'C:<<path>>\AppData\Local\Temp\26\RtmpANG4o2/fonts/ahronbd.afm'
2: In readLines(srcfile) :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:<<path>>\AppData\Local\Temp\26\RtmpANG4o2/fonts/ahronbd.afm'

etc.
```

When I run this code:

```
loadfonts()
fonts()
```

the output is `NULL`

and when I try to save a ggplot as a pdf using `ggsave()`, the error says:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid font type
```

I guess that last error is not that surprising as the font table seems empty.

What's going wrong here and how can this problem be solved?

**EDIT** I thought I found the solution. When I use `loadfonts(device="win")` instead of `loadfonts()` all seemed to go well at first, but I was wrong. `fonts()` is still empty.

Comment: Try   `names(pdfFonts())`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It shows the fonts that are available. The fonts that should have been there through `font_import()` are not snown.

Answer (score 0):

For any exasperated searches out there, I had the same issue on Windows, and solved it with:

```
font_import(paths = "C:/Path_to_font")
```

Now `fonts()` should populate. I found the path to fonts in **Font preview and related settings** and clicking on the relevant font. Presumably most of your fonts are in the same place.